# I want to return a the length of the string using 2 methods. Newbie in Java

Tags: java

I have errors when I run program(1). But when I used program(2), writing 0 after a, it run and produced the correct output. Writing 0, is just my guess and somehow it worked. Why is that?

**Program (1):**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(a);

    }

    private static int a(int len) {
        String s = "What";
        len = s.length();
        return (len);
    }
}
```

**Program (2):**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(a(0));

    }

    private static int a(int len) {
        String s = "What";
        len = s.length();
        return (len);
    }
}
```

Comment: You directly have `length()` right away then why to create new method for that

Comment: I was just trying to use methods for strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote the function in such a way that it requires a parameter. To call a function that requires a parameter, you have to supply one. That's why the second program worked--you gave the function a a parameter of 0.

To make the first program work, then, you have two options. The first is what you did--supply the required parameter for the function. The second is to modify the function declaration so it does not require a parameter, changing

```
private static int a(int len) {
```

to

```
private static int a() {
```

Comment: Well, you still need to add parens to make it a function call, a()

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(a);
}

private static int a(int len) {
    String s = "What";
    len = s.length();
    return (len);
}
```

The problem here is that `a` is a function which receives a single integer parameter. This code is therefore a compilation error:

```
System.out.println(a);
```

You cannot print a *function*. What you can do is call a function and print that function's return value. Which is precisely what your second chunk of code does.

However, since your function `a` ignores its input parameter, you could re-write the code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(a());
}

private static int a() {
    String s = "What";
    int len = s.length();
    return len;
}
```

Note that you still need to call the function using parentheses, `a()`. But because there is no longer a parameter required, you can leave the parameter list empty.

Comment: Can you elaborate more, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this really has nothing to do with the string length part. It's just simple method calling.)

Well look at this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println(a);
}
```

That's trying to use `a` as if it's a variable - it's not, it's a *method*. So you want to *invoke* that method, and use the return value, which is what you do in your second version.

Admittedly it's pretty odd to pass in an argument and then not use it, and likewise you've got unnecessary parentheses around your return value - `return` isn't a method call.

So your code can be simplified to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println(a());   
}

private static int a() {
    return "What".length();
}
```

Or if you really want the local variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    System.out.println(a());   
}

private static int a() {
    String s = "What";
    return s.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing method parameters with normal variable declarations.  You've written `a` as a method that takes a single `int` parameter, so you need to pass it a value; but you don't actually use that value in the body of the function.

You probably really want to use a local variable, and not pass a parameter at all, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(a());

}

private static int a() {
    String s = "What";
    int len = s.length();
    return (len);
```

Note that you still need to write `a()` in the call, not just `a`, to make clear that it is a method call.

Answer (score 0):

The first code can't compile as you are trying to output a variable `a` that has not been declared (this syntax is not a method call). In the second one you are actually calling the static method `a` that exists, so it runs.

Comment: @jzworkman I know, I'm just explaining to him that in this case it is not a method call but treated as a variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

a is a function not a variable. You cannot call a function without the paranthesis... 
you would have to type in a() to call the function. 
Now, what happens in the first case is, since there are missing paranthesis it tries to resolve it as a variable and errors out.

The second case is where you call the function in the correct fashion

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on how to make method calls.  This is one of the most basic things you will be doing in java.

When you want to call method a, you need to pass the correct number of arguments(in this case a single int) or the method call will not be recognized and be an error.  What IDE are you using to develop your java code? If you are using something like Eclipse you shouldnt even be able to run the code with this error present.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `a` is defined as a function that takes a single argument, which is named `len`. When you call it as `a(0)`, you provide that argument and everything works just fine. When you call it as `a`, you do not provide that argument and compilation fails. The code never runs.

The question is: why have you defined `a` to take an argument? It isn't used: its value is immediately overwritten with the result of `s.length()`.

It seems like you are attempting to declare a local variable for use by mentioning it in the function signature. That does is not necessary, and does not work, in Java.